# Replace a matching string in each line with another string

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to replace the number at the end of every line of a given file with an incremented number(+1).

My Input file looks like

C:\documents\a.txt,1988,15.01.00.0059

C:\documents\we.txt,1988,15.01.00.0059

C:\documents\gh.txt,1987,1988,15.01.00.0059

my out put file should be

C:\documents\a.txt,1988,15.01.00.0060

C:\documents\we.txt,1988,15.01.00.0060

C:\documents\gh.txt,1988,15.01.00.0060

My attempt is like

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search="

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%i in (%1) do (
@echo %%i %%j %%k
set "search=%%k"
)

set "replace="
REM @echo %replace%

set "textFile=%1"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

i could able to get 15.01.00.0059 from the input file but dont know how to change to 15.01.00.0060 .

replacing to the same input file is also working . I just need to know how to increment the value and assign to "replace".

Thank you

Bhargav.k

Comment: You probably want to look at using an arthmetic type command, and as the only one is `Set` with its `/A` option, and it only works with integers, the task is not straight forward. You'd have to take each line, split the comtent of it at the laast period, prepend that with one or more digits to prevent issues with leading `0`'s, increment that result by `1`, then make your replacement. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `set /?`, press the 'ENTER' key, and read its usage information.

Comment: Simple using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - `jrepl \d+$ "$txt=lpad(parseInt($0,10)+1,$0.length,'0')" /jq /f file.txt /o -`

Answer (score 0):

This should be flexible enough:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

1>out.txt (
    FOR /F tokens^=*^ delims^=.^ eol^= %%L in (input.txt) do (
        set "line=%%L"
        set "x=!line:.= !"
        FOR %%T in (!x!) do set "lastToken=%%T"

        cmd /c exit /b !lastToken!
        set/a"lstrip=!ERRORLEVEL!+1"

        >getlen.tmp echo(!lasttoken!
        FOR %%L in (getlen.tmp) do set/a"len=%%~zL-2" %= get length of last token, minus CRLF =%

        FOR %%N in (1 1 !len!) do set "lstrip=0!lstrip!" PREFIX lstrip with zeroes

        FOR %%N in (!len!) do (
            set "lstrip=!lstrip:~-%%N!"
            echo !line:~0,-%%N!!lstrip!
        )
    )
)
del getlen.tmp

ENDLOCAL
```

This is not a straightforward approach.
The script counts the # of zeroes prefixed before the last token by the `ERRORLEVEL` returned by `EXIT /B`, compared with the original token.

Comment: This is working perfect !! thanks a lot.. Could you please explain the base logic..at least for loops..

Comment: `FOR /F tokens^=*^ delims^=.^ eol^= %%L in (input.txt)` loops through each line of `input.txt`, skipping empty/delimiter-only lines